Salto de líneas en entradas de datos en R
Estoy agregando una base de datos txt en R, pero al momento de cargar los datos en algunas entradas (filas) se dividen en dos filas lo que hace que tengas mas filas de las esperadas, como puedo solucionar esta parte en R?

Hola @COMACIT, bienvenido a Stackoverflow Español, para que se te pueda brindar una respuesta que solucione tu problema podrías agregar un pequeño ejemplo que reproduzca tu problema, acá podés ver cómo se hace dicho ejemplo.


Identifica como están separadas la columnas de tu base de datos, por ejemplo yo lo tengo definido de esta manera en un archivo llamado data.txt, y están separados por una coma ,.

root@fac116c7c600:~# cat /home/rstudio/data.txt 

Nombre,Edad,Genero
Juan,25,M
Maria,30,F
Pedro,40,M


En la consola de R al momento de cargar los datos debes especificar como están separadas las columnas.

> datos <- read.csv("/home/rstudio/data.txt", sep = ",")
> print(datos)
  Nombre Edad Genero
1   Juan   25      M
2  Maria   30      F
3  Pedro   40      M


Reproducción de la solución:


Mis datos se cargan de esta forma por unos saltos de línea que vienen en el TXT
ID_NOMBRE | ENTIDAD | TIPO | CLASE
023445 | TAB | 2 | A
244567 | COL | 3 | B
988324
COL | 2 |A
097523 | VER |4 | 6
988345 |MOR |3 |4
Cuando cargo en R
ID_NOMBRE  ENTIDAD   TIPO    CLASE
1   023445        TAB            2           A
2   244567        COL           3            B
3   988324
4    COL            2                A
5   097523        VER            4           6
6
7   988345        MOR          3           4
